# Google map in TabHost in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using tabhost in my Project with 4 tab. Out of 4 tab 2 tab( tab3 and tab4) contain Map Activity where we show map in both activity. When my app first start and i press tab3 then map will be show proper but after that I press tab4 then tab3 map show in tab4 always same condition tab4 to tab3.
How can I solve this..

Comment: you meant the map is not updating?

Answer (score 0):

In tab host the child tabactivities are created once when the RootActivity is created. So the onCreate Method will be called once. My guess is you have updated the map in the onCreate method of the Tab Activity. That's why it is not updating properly.

If so then Instead of updating the map in onCreate, update them in on onResume method.